# Syntax Error testfork C code

Tags: c, syntax-error

We are supposed to be using this code that was provided to us in class to learn how forks work and the differences we see with different inputs. My only problem here is that I'm receiving syntax errors when I attempt to run the code so I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to clarify how I was running this. School has a UNIX machine that I connect to to run this. After compiling it just a matter of running it with its filename which is testfork.c

Error outputs:

```
./testfork.c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./testfork.c: line 6: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])'
```

Codeblock:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pid_t childpid;  int count;

   if (argc < 2) {
      printf("usage: testfork count\n");
      return -1;
   }
   else count = atoi(argv[1]);

   childpid = fork();

   if (childpid == -1) {
      printf("Error in fork; program terminated\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if (childpid != 0) {
      /*Code executed by parent process*/
      int i;

      /*The lines below will avoid output interleaving*/
      /*int status;*/
      /*wait(&status);*/

      for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
         printf("parent process\n");
   }
   else {
      /*Code executed by child process*/
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
         printf("                       CHILD PROCESS\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this?

Comment: I assume you are using `sh` to run this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be right (I'm talking only about the syntax here), and I can compile and run it perfectly fine on my computer. So the problem might comes from the way you compile/run the file. This is a .c file, so you might want to use the `gcc` compiler, for example :

`gcc your_file.c -o your_exe -Wall -Wextra` (the `-Wall -Wextra` is optionnal but this is always a good habit).

Then you will find a new file called `your_exe` that you can execute like this `./your_exe` (assuming you are on a Linux machine).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

just tried this

```
sh-4.3$ gcc -o testforkx testfork.c                                                                                                                                                                           
sh-4.3$ ls                                                                                                                                                                                                    
testfork.c  testforkx                                                                                                                                                                                         
sh-4.3$ ./testforkx 12
```

Here was the output i get :

```
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
parent process
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
                   CHILD PROCESS
```

Did not see any syntax errors in the program